# Golang: Processing 5 huge files concurrently

Tags: go

I have 5 huge (4 million rows each) logfiles that I process in Perl currently and I thought I may try to implement the same in Go and its concurrent features. So, being very inexperienced in Go, I was thinking of doing as below. Any comments on the approach will be greatly appreciated.
Some rough pseudocode:

```
var wg1 sync.WaitGroup
var wg2 sync.WaitGroup

func processRow (r Row) {
    wg2.Add(1)
    defer wg2.Done()
    res = <process r>
    return res
}

func processFile(f File) {
    wg1.Add(1)
    open(newfile File)
    defer wg1.Done()
    line = <row from f>
    result = go processRow(line)
    newFile.Println(result) // Write new processed line to newFile
    wg2.Wait()
    newFile.Close()

}

func main() {

    for each f logfile {
        go processFile(f)
    }
    wg1.Wait()
}
```

So, idea is that I process these 5 files concurrently and then all rows of each file will in turn also be processed concurrently.

Will that work?

Comment: For i/o bound tasks you might not get all that much from CPU concurrency. You might want to look into channels, too.

Comment: What the "process r" is? If it is something relatively "easy" it might not be worth to do it in separate gorutine - overhead is bigger than gain. Also, as the result, will you have one "log data set" (ie all 5 files are merged to one) or will there be 5 different resultsets?

Comment: @ain My understanding is that it would have to be *pretty* insubstantial. The overhead of goroutines is INCREDIBLY low.

Comment: @salvador No, not hard to implement, but I won't get to a development environment before middle of next week. Was curious to know what other people thought of the idea.

Comment: @ain There will be 5 separate result files, one for each source file. Also, "process r" easy enough, but there is some processing to be done. e.g Regexes, convert from hex to decimal, output in csv

Comment: @AdamSmith Yes, but it all adds up (adding to waitgroup too) and if the proccessing is really simple then it just isn't worth to do it.

Comment: Do you need the row results to be output in the same order as in the input file?

Comment: @Jean No, order does not matter at all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should definitely use channels to manage your processed rows. Alternatively you could also write another goroutine to handle your output.

```
var numGoWriters = 10

func processRow(r Row, ch chan<- string) {
    res := process(r)
    ch <- res
}

func writeRow(f File, ch <-chan string) {
    w := bufio.NewWriter(f)
    for s := range ch {
        _, err := w.WriteString(s + "\n")
    }

func processFile(f File) {
    outFile, err := os.Create("/path/to/file.out")
    if err != nil {
        // handle it
    }
    defer outFile.Close()
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    ch := make(chan string, 10)  // play with this number for performance
    defer close(ch) // once we're done processing rows, we close the channel
                    // so our worker threads exit
    fScanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    for fScanner.Scan() {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            processRow(fScanner.Text(), ch)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    for i := 0; i < numGoWriters; i++ {
        go writeRow(outFile, ch)
    }
    wg.Wait()  
}
```

Here we have `processRow` doing all the processing (I assumed to `string`), `writeRow` doing all the out I/O, and `processFile` tying each file together. Then all `main` has to do is hand off the files, spawn the goroutines, *et voila*.

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    filenames := [...]string{"here", "are", "some", "log", "paths"}
    for fname := range filenames {
        inFile, err := os.Open(fname)
        if err != nil {
            // handle it
        }
        defer inFile.Close()
        wg.Add(1)
        go processFile(inFile)
    }
    wg.Wait()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this!